# Function from C++ not receiving correct arguments called in Rust

Tags: c++, rust, ffi, extern

Im trying to link *.cc into rust.

build.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
    cc::Build::new()
        .file("src/bindings.cc")
        .cargo_metadata(true)
        .cpp(true)
        .compile("bindings");
}
```

bindings.cc:

```cpp
extern "C" {
    leveldb::Status db_get(
        LevelDB* db,
        const char* key, size_t keylen,
        const char** val, size_t* vallen,
        bool fillCache
    ) {
        printf("0: %p, 1: %p, 2: %d, 3: %p, 4: %p, 5: %s\n",
            db,
            key, keylen,
            val, vallen,
            fillCache ? "true" : "false"
        );
        leveldb::Status status;
        return status;
    }
}
```

sys.rs:

```rust
enum LevelDB {}

// why? leveldb::Status has private property const char*
// It doesnt matter, this is just a test code
#[repr(C)]
struct Status(NonNull<u8>);

#[link(name = "bindings")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn db_get(
        db: *mut LevelDB,
        key: *const u8, keylen: usize,
        val: *mut *const u8, vallen: *mut usize,
        fill_cache: bool
    ) -> Status;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```rust
println!("0: {:?}, 1: {:?}, 2: {:?}, 3: {:?}, 4: {:?}, 5: {}",
    self.raw.as_ptr(),
    key.as_ptr(), key.len(),
    &mut val, &mut len,
    options.fill_cache
);

let status = sys::db_get(
    self.raw.as_ptr(),
    key.as_ptr(), key.len(),
    &mut val, &mut len,
    options.fill_cache
);
```

Now, as I run it, it prints:

```
0: 0x58aa2fc8a700, 1: 0x58aa2fc8a6e0, 2: 9, 3: 0x0, 4: 0, 5: true
0: 0x58aa2fc8a6e0, 1: 0x9, 2: 1439424216, 3: 0x7fff55cbdee0, 4: 0x1, 5: true
```

The pointer may be different every time I ran it but its still the same, unaligned with what I intend to supply in the rust code. I assure you that I calculated the extern function argument type size and made sure that they are equal in the rust side, same for the return type. I debugged it and made sure they have the same size. From observations alone, i can see that the arguments are shifted to the left. I could not pinpoint the problem

Comment: Can you include the missing type definitions (`LevelDB` and `Status`) so your sample is complete? (I wouldn't expect it to make a difference unless `LevelDB` was an unsized type in Rust or something, but it doesn't hurt to make sure).

Comment: `println!` with `&mut val` will print the value behind the reference, not the address of the reference like `printf` with `const char** val` later.

Comment: I imagine this is because you're using Debug formatting instead of pointer formatting. Here's an example in just Rust: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4711ceb7e30bdd3c8963287ca89d71b Try `0: {:p}, 1: {:p}, 2: {}, 3: {:p}, 4: {:p}, 5: {}` on your Rust side.

Comment: Unrelated, but just a piece of advice... stop using leveldb. It's a piece of garbage.

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist, its for minecraft, so i cant avoid it

Comment: @PitaJ i dont think its because on printing. If i run it on my functional code on cc, it will fail SIGSEGV

Comment: There are two issues: one is that the args are shifted: arg 0 from Rust is missing in C++, then arg 1 from Rust is seen as arg 0 from C++ and so on. And the second issue is with printing the references in Rust (printing `(&mut val) as *mut _` should fix that). I don't know why the arguments are shifted though…

Comment: Can't reproduce on my machine.